# Azure HTTP Trigger Function Authorization by roles claim in JWT from Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, .net-core, azure-functions

I have an Azure HTTP Trigger Function uses Azure Active Directory for authentication. This works great, but I am hoping that I can protect each individual function with a method attribute that verifies the role(s) of an authenticated principal. I found the `Authorize` attribute to be what I think I'm looking for.

For example:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "myCustomRole")]
[FunctionName("myTriggerFunction")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
       [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal,
        ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("Welcome " + claimsPrincipal.Identity.Name);
}
```

I can dig in to the `ClaimsPrincipal` object and ultimately get to the roles claim (and everything else from the JWT) with the values using something like this:

```
foreach (Claim claim in claimsPrincipal.Claims)
{
    log.logInformation("CLAIM TYPE: " + claim.Type + "; CLAIM VALUE: " + claim.Value);
}
```

I would prefer to be able to protect each method with an attribute. Is this something that can easily be done?